# Persisting keyboard light state on boot/shutdown

Tags: macbook

2011 8,3 Macbook Pro running 64bit 11.10.

The keyboard backlight keys are working great, but how can I make them persist state across reboots? I'd like to record the current keyboard backlight state when shutting down and restore it when starting up so as to make things super cool and seamless from reboot to reboot.

Is this possible? Is there a way that I could write a script to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This utility may satisfy you: https://launchpad.net/~poliva/+archive/lightum-mba

Hope it could be polished and merged to standard Ubuntu some time later.